# create a dataframe from for loop output

Tags: python, pandas

I need to create a dataframe from the output of the following for loop.

I tried writing a for loop but I do not know how to make the results into a dataframe. I also need to count the number of occurrences of each activity.

```
for c in final_merged.columns:
 print(final_merged[c].value_counts())
```

The output looks like this:

```
golf     3
soccer   3
fishing  1
soccer   2
```

But this output is not a dataframe.

I need the output to look like this:

```
activity  count
golf        3
soccer      5
fishing     1
```

Answer (score 0):

Fix your output

```
output.sum(level=0)
```

Or using `stack`

```
final_merged.stack().value_counts()
```

Or `numpy` way `unique`

```
v,c=np.unique(df.values.ravel(),return_counts =True)
pd.Series(c,index=v)
```

Comment: Thanks! final_merged.stack().value_counts() works, but how do I get the output to be 2 columns?  Ultimately, I want to be able to sum up the total number of counts.

Comment: @Ashley `final_merged.stack().value_counts().to_frame('count').reset_index()`

Comment: I think you need change your code for DataFrame, not Series.

Answer (score 0):

If use `value_counts` it return unique index, so aggregate `sum` is not necessary.

For DataFrame use [`Series.rename_axis`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.rename_axis.html) with [`Series.reset_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.reset_index.html):

```
for c in final_merged.columns:
    print(final_merged[c].value_counts().rename_axis('activity').reset_index(name='count'))
```

If need DataFrame from all columns add [`DataFrame.stack`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html):

```
df = final_merged.stack().value_counts().rename_axis('activity').reset_index(name='count')
```