# Save data frame from inside for loop

Tags: python, pandas, loops, for-loop

I have a function that takes in a `dataframe` and returns a (reduced) `dataframe`, e.g. like this:

```
def transforming_data(dataframe, col_1, col_2, normalized = True):
    ''' takes in dataframe, groups col_1 according to col_2 and returns dataframe
    '''
    df = dataframe[col_1].groupby(dataframe[col_2]).value_counts(normalize = normalized).unstack(fill_value = 0)

    return dataframe
```

For the following code, this gives me:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
np.random.seed(12)

def transforming_data(df, col_1, col_2, normalized = True):
    ''' takes in df, groups col_1 according to col_2 and returns df '''
    df = dataframe[col_1].groupby(dataframe[col_2]).value_counts(normalize = normalized).unstack(fill_value = 0)
    return df

numrows = 1000
dataframe = pd.DataFrame({'Numerical': np.random.randn(numrows), 
                         'Category': np.random.choice(['Panda', 'Elephant', 'Anaconda'], numrows),
                         'Response 1': np.random.choice(['Yes', 'Maybe', 'No', 'Don\'t know'], numrows),
                         'Response 2': np.random.choice(['Very Much', 'Much', 'A bit', 'Not at all'], numrows)})

test = transforming_data(dataframe, 'Response 1', 'Category')
print(test)
# Output
# Response 1  Don't know     Maybe        No       Yes
# Category                                            
# Anaconda      0.275229  0.232416  0.217125  0.275229
# Elephant      0.220588  0.270588  0.255882  0.252941
# Panda         0.258258  0.222222  0.273273  0.246246
```

**So far, so good.**

Now I want to use the function `transforming_data` inside a `for` loop for every column in `dataframe` (as I have lots of columns, not just two) and save the resulting dataframe to a new dataframe, e.g. `test_response_1` and `test_response_2` for this example.

Can someone point me in the right direction - i.e. how to implement the loop correctly?

So far, I am using something  like this - but cannot figure out how to *save* the data frame

```
for column in dataframe.columns.tolist():
    temp_df = transforming_data(dataframe, column, 'Category')
    # here, I need to save tmp_df outside of the loop but don't know how to
```

Thanks a lot for pointers and help. (Note: the [most similar question I found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56086874/create-a-dataframe-from-for-loop-output) does not talk about actually saving the data frame, so it doesn't help me with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save (in memory) all of the `temp_df`'s from your loop, you can append them to a list that you can then index afterwards:

```py
temp_dfs = []
for column in dataframe.columns.tolist(): #you don't actually need the tolist() method here
    temp_df = transforming_data(dataframe, column, 'Category')
    temp_dfs.append(temp_df)
```

If you rather be able to access these `temp_df`'s by the column name that was used to transform them, then you could assign each to a dictionary, using the column as the key:

```py
temp_dfs = {}
for column in dataframe.columns.tolist():
    temp_df = transforming_data(dataframe, column, 'Category')
    temp_dfs[column] = temp_df
```

If by "save" you meant "write to disk", then you can use one of the many `to_<file_format>()` methods that pandas provides:

```py
temp_dfs = {}
for column in dataframe.columns.tolist():
    temp_df = transforming_data(dataframe, column, 'Category')
    temp_df.to_csv('temp_df{}.csv'.format(column))
```

Here's the `to_csv()` [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_csv.html).

Answer (score 1):

The most simple solution would be to save the result dataframes into a list. Assuming that all columns that you want to loop over have the text `Response` in their column name:

```
result_dframes = []
for col_name in dataframe.filter(like='Response').columns:
    result_dframe = transforming_data(dataframe, col_name, 'Category')
    result_dframes.append(result_dframe)
```

Alternatively you can also obtain the exact same result with a [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) instead of a for-loop:

```
result_dframes = [
    transforming_data(dataframe, col_name, 'Category')
    for col_name in dataframe.filter(like='Response')
]
```